# Assigning another viewcontroller at initWithNib

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad, ios4

I am just curious if lets per say I have a singleton property of webView I am trying to assign at the initialization point of another viewController. The compiler is generating the error indicating "Incompatible pointer types".

I am not sure why it is doing so, as the Super Class of that Class is still UIViewController. Any help here would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Code below:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if (self) {

        // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would
        if ([[CartCheckout sharedInstance] universalVC]) {
            //self = [[CartCheckout sharedInstance] universalVC];
            NSLog(@"testing");
            self = [[CartCheckout sharedInstance] universalVC];
        }
        NSLog(@"initWithNibName allocated");
    }

    return self; }
```

Comment: you should probably post some code

Comment: I think your question is still vague. Which line is giving the error? What class is this code from? What type of object does `[[CartCheckout sharedInstance] universalVC]` return? (I assume it's a `CartCheckout`)  What is your class hierarchy like?

Comment: nielsbot, this line self = [[CartCheckout sharedInstance] universalVC]; is what is causing the error. UniversalVC is a property in CartCheckout class of uiviewcontroller, whereas CartChechout is a NSObject type class.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the view controller of the actual instance you are trying to do the assignment to is not of the correct type, it doesnt matter that they share a super class.

self in this case is of one and only one type, the type of the view controller subclass.

Also, even if they were the same type, Objective C is not going to let you replace the instance of the class in an init method with anything.

init methods are instance allocation methods, if you return a pointer to something besides the instance you are actually in, you are going to crash immediately following.

So you have two problems, one, you are trying to inject a singleton instance into an init method, and two you are trying to hijack the container of a view.

Neither of these will work.  Instantiate the correct type of viewController to go with your view at the time you need it.

What you want instead is this:

```
MyUniversalViewController *universalVC = [MyUniversalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"blabla
```

Trying to switch types in the constructor is too late.